# Filtering Solr child documents by date range

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have a set of Solr documents with children, and each child has a `startDate_dt` and an `endDate_dt`, and I want my queries to only return valid children, i.e. children for which the current date is between the start date and the end date.

Since I'm already using the [ChildDocTransformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_child_-ChildDocTransformerFactory) I was hoping I'd be able to set the childFilter to a date range in the `fl` field:

```
*, [child parentFilter=docType:"VEHICLE" childFilter=promotion.startDate_dt:[2018-04-03T00:00:00Z TO *] AND promotion.endDate_dt:[* TO 2018-04-03T23:00:00Z]]
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I'm getting an exception with message `error parsing fieldname`.

I tried filtering for a single value, i.e.

```
*, [child parentFilter=docType:"VEHICLE" childFilter=promotion.startDate_dt:"2018-04-03T00:00:00Z"]
```

And it works properly, so I'm guessing there's an issue in the syntax I'm using to specify date ranges.

What am I missing? Is there a way to filter child documents by date ranges?

Comment: I believe if you have multiple fields you need to wrap the childFilter in quotations so it'd be like childFIlter="promotion.startDate_dt:[your ranges] AND promotion.endDate_dt:[your ranges]"

Comment: Any updates around this ? Facing similar issue